# Android app name doesn't display in all activities

Tags: java, android

The title of the app was hidden after adding side navigation bar. This is AndroidManifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".QRCode" />
</application>
```

Please resolve this problem... Regards

Comment: Can you provide a screen shot?

Answer (score 0):

Add application name to the app:

```
<application android:name="xxxx"
   android:label="@string/xxx"
   android:icon="@drawable/xxx">
```

After this, the best is add name to activities:

```
<activity android:name="ApiDemos">
     <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.xxxx" />
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
     </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also add title of the activity by the method called 
`setTitle("Activity name")` in the onCreate() method of the activity.